# I do not have idea what am doing wrong. in the below stream api related code snippet

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Following is the code that gives me error "Bad return type in lambda expression: U cannot be converted to Integer". I do not understand why it needs Integer here as the keys are String.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input="java is headache";
        //-1st non repeated char using stream
        String [] arr= input.split("");
        List<String> myList= Arrays.asList(arr);
        System.out.println(myList);

        Map<String ,Long > myMap=myList.stream()
                .collect(toMap(Function.identity(), String::length,
                *(e1, e2) -> e2*, LinkedHashMap::new));




    }
```

Highlighted area is the piece of code showing as incorrect in the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrectly declared the type of  `myMap`, which throws off the compiler:

```
        Map<String, Integer> myMap = myList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), String::length,
                        (e1, e2) -> e2, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

In general, the compiler often gives generics-related errors in the wrong place. It can help to separate out all parts, and explicitly typing them. In this case, I extracted the third parameter to a `BinaryOperator<Integer>` variable, which pointed me to the real error.

Comment: Printing your `Map` gives `{j=1, a=1, v=1,  =1, i=1, s=1, h=1, e=1, d=1, c=1}`. What is that telling you?

Comment: @g00se that it's working? I'm not sure what you're trying to say

Comment: No, I'm wondering what info it's giving to the user

Comment: @g00se I mean, the logical assumption is they wanted a character count. Changing the combinator function to `(e1, e2) -> e1 + e2` would do that. But that's not the point of either the question or the answer.

Comment: "It is working" implies that it *is* giving the required output. I'm just curious as to what that is